# popViewController() doesn't work after rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I start the second view controller from the first view controller

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Then I get back to the first view controller from the second one like this:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

It works ok until phone orientation is changed from *landscapeRight > landscapeLeft > landscapeRight* (during second view controller)

So after *landscapeRight > landscapeLeft > landscapeRight* `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` stops working

It doesn't open the first second controller anymore

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please check if you are performing any activity while orientation is Changed in override func viewWillTransition ?

Comment: @Rizwan I don't override `viewWillTransition` in the second view controller

Comment: Do you override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` in one of viewControllers?

Comment: @Kerberos no, I don't override

Comment: What is the event for popViewController(), Back icon or some other button ? Possibly after the orientation changed the button or icon on which the event is bind to move out of screen bounds. Please put a log just before where you are actually calling popViewController() and check once.

Comment: @Rizwan everything is ok with button, I already put print functions there, everything is ok, it just doesn't return to first activity

Comment: @user155 - this issue is quite interesting. Is it possible for you to share the codebase. I would like to debug and identify the issue in it.

Comment: @Rizwan I used this library (video player), https://github.com/VeinGuo/VGPlayer seems it somehow causes this issue